# my api data cannot process with model swift

Tags: swift, api, url, swiftui, model

its my model. quicktyper site translated my model

```
import  Foundation


struct User: Codable {
    let customerID, companyID: Int
    let firstName, lastName, phone, email: String
    let passwordHash, passwordSalt: JSONNull?
    let isStatus: Bool
}

struct Data : Codable{
    let custommodel : [User]
}

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

its my api request

```
import Foundation



enum Verierror: Error{
    
    case noDatAvailable
    case canNotProcessData
    
}
struct verirequest{
    let resource : URL
    //example url. this is not the truth
    let resoucreString = ""
   
    init() {
       
        guard let resourceurll = URL(string: resoucreString) else {fatalError()}
        self.resource = resourceurll
    }
    
    
    func getveri(completion: @escaping(Result<[User],Verierror>) -> Void){
        let datatask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource) { data, _, _ in
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
            guard let jsondata = data else{
                completion(.failure(.noDatAvailable))
                
                return
            }
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let veriresponse = try decoder.decode(Data.self, from: jsondata)
                let details = veriresponse.custommodel
               
                
                completion(.success(details))
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
            }
        }
        datatask.resume()
    }
    
}
```

My data is coming from API, but my data cannot be processed. I get a "cannotprocesdata" error. I was able to process at first but now I can't.
I translated my model to quictyper.com. At the same time, I get the error "Cannot process data" in the output.

There is no problem in api, I can test it in postman.
Could the problem be with my model or elsewhere?.
please Help me

its my view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
 

    
    
    var listveri = [User]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self
       
        
        let verirequest = verirequest()
        verirequest.getveri { [weak self] (result) in
            switch result{
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case.success(let data):
                self?.listveri = data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
        
        }
    
       
     
       
    }
   
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listveri.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
      
       
        
        cell.namelabel.text = listveri[indexPath.row].firstName
        cell.surnamelabel.text = listveri[indexPath.row].lastName
        cell.emaillabel.text = listveri[indexPath.row].email
        return cell
    }
    

  
 


}
```

Comment: Do you have sample/example of the data been returned by your endpoint?  You should also probably print the error which is been captured by the `catch` block

Comment: show us the json data you are getting from the server, by adding: `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`
just before `guard let jsondata = ....`. PS: do not use the name `Data` for your struct, Swift has already a `Data` struct, this may confuse the compiler.

Comment: copy and paste this json data into: `https://app.quicktype.io/`, not your `quicktyper` thing. And you will see what you need to do.

Comment: I already bought it from that site. but its not working. my model is taken above

Comment: I don't understand.I use app.quicktype.io but its not working :( I get same error

Comment: your `struct Data : Codable{
    let custommodel : [User]
}` is not correct, see my answer. You need to use `data` not `custommodel`. The `quicktype` tells you this.

Comment: its my catch error = typeMismatch(apii.JSONNull, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "passwordHash", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: When I export the data to quicktype, it gives me the above model.

Comment: No it does not give you `custommodel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following structs :

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let data: [User]   // <--- here
    let message: String?
    let success: Bool
}

struct User: Codable {
    let customerID, companyID: Int
    let firstName, lastName, phone, email: String
    let passwordHash, passwordSalt: String?
    let isStatus: Bool
}
```

and decode the server response like this:

```
   let veriresponse = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsondata)
```

Comment: yes I tried but I get same error = "cannotprocessdata"

Comment: its my catch error = typeMismatch(apii.JSONNull, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "passwordHash", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Replace `JSONNull?` with `String?` in `Response` and `User`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Can you explain it.  
how did it work

Comment: All I did is to use `quicktype`, nothing magic here. You should not change the key names, because this is what makes everything works 
with the json data.
The code (structs) will work with `JSONNull?`, but it seems easier to use `String?`
If this answer your question, could you mark it as correct, with the tick mark, thank you.